# What is the proper way to define the collection name at the application startup with MongoEngine?

Tags: python, flask, flask-mongoengine

I use MongoEngine as an ODM in my Flask application. Depending on the passed configuration document, MongoEngine should use a different collection.

At the moment I achieve this by changing the internal meta variable `model._meta['collection']`. Is there an alternative for selecting the collection?

```py
from mongoengine import connect
from api_service.model import MyModel


create_app(config):

app = Flask(__name__)

# load app.config 

connect(app.config['MONGODB_DB'],
        host=app.config['MONGODB_HOST'],
        port=app.config['MONGODB_PORT'],
        username=app.config['MONGODB_USERNAME'],
        password=app.config['MONGODB_PASSWORD'],
        )



MyModel._meta['collection'] = app.config['MONGODB_MYMODEL_COLLECTION']
```

I know that you can define the collection by `meta:{}` in the class body of the model (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976963/specifying-collection-name-with-mongoengine)). But I am not in the app context there and therefore I cannot access `app.config'.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify the `meta` attribute inside the class itself

```
class MyModel(Document):
    meta = {"collection": "my_actual_collection_name"}
    ...
```

[Check This for more meta attributes you can use](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-collections)

---

## Solution Update

I defined a helper class that can have a provide an access the application's configurations

```
class AppConfigHelper:
    from flask import current_app
    APP_CONFIG = current_app.config
```

and in the document import and use that class to get the collection name.

```
class MyModel(Document):
    meta = {'collection': AppConfigHelper.APP_CONFIG['MONGODB_MYMODEL_COLLECTION']}
    ...
```

This is not the best solution I can think of, but it does the job.

---

> **Caution**: this is not gonna work if you run it separately from `Flask`, it is going to crash, you can run it inside the app itself, or using `flask shell`

Comment: Please read the last two lines of my question. I exclude your suggestion in my question since I am not within the app context inside the model class. I need to be in the app context because I want to read the database collection name from `app.config`. 

Do you have a suggestion for this approach?

Comment: @Mol1narius sorry about that, I will try to alter my code and see how I am gonna cover such case.

Comment: The moment I import my model in a module a Runtime Error is generated since it is not I call current app outside the application context.